# nodejs get all collection from mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've defined simple connection to mongo db to fetch all saved records into database and show I get null and my `findAll` does not work:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

ArticleProvider = function (host, port) {
    this.db = new Db('article', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}), {safe:false});
    this.db.open(function () {
    });
};

ArticleProvider.prototype.getCollection = function (callback) {
    this.db.collection('article'), function (error, article_collection) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        else callback(null, article_collection);
    }
};

ArticleProvider.prototype.findAll = function(callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, article_collection) {
        if( error ) callback(error)
        else {
            article_collection.find().toArray(function(error, results) {
                if( error ) callback(error)
                else callback(null, results)
            });
        }
    });
};

exports.ArticleProvider = ArticleProvider;
```

for get all saved data in `article` database, i'm testing log and find all saved records into `article` from mongo shell:

```
> db.article.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55033f527be6c3a7bc7e5b04"), "title" : "Post two", "body" : "Body two" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55033f527be6c3a7bc7e5b05"), "title" : "Post three", "body" : "Body three" }
>
```

**in my nodejs Route i get null and i can not get this records from my application**

My nodejs server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('../')(server);
var connect = require('connect');
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.json());  
app.use(connect.urlencoded());


require('../routes/routes.js')(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

My Route content file:

```
var ArticleProvider = require('config/models/connection').ArticleProvider;
var articleProvider = new ArticleProvider('localhost', 27017);

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){
            console.log(docs);
        });
        res.end();
    });

};
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  You seem to discard any errors

Comment: @ExplosionPills no sir i dont get error. i get null for result, i have some record in database but i get null

Comment: Actually I think it's just a semantics issue: `this.db.collection('article', ` not `this.db.collection('article'),`

Answer (score 0):

You #getCollection method on the ArticleProvider prototype property has a syntax error, for starters. You could get rid of #getCollection all together, not sure what you are doing with it. I think you are trying to just query the db for all the article documents in that collection? Try this:

```
ArticleProvider.prototype.findAll = function(callback) {
  this.db.collection('article').find({}, function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      callback(null, results);
    }
  });
};
```